# Listview shows overflow issue on right side

Tags: flutter

I have below code to display 2 cards and trying to have horizontal movement. Listview is already in place. Axis direction is horizontal.

Still there is overflow issue in right side. Also tried shrink wrap but did not work.

Issue can be easily replicated on dart pad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/dart? just copy the below code.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(body: HomeScreen()),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            Text("Text 1", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Text("Text 2", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
          ]),
          ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Card(
                  child: Container(
                height: 230,
                width: 170,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 170,
                      width: 150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/user.png"))),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `column` and `row` inside your `listview` and then added both `cards`  into your `row widget` This is the wrong approach so you just need to separate this all first. So I change your code and added `scrollDirection` also wrap your listview with `Container` for giving height and margin. You can check following answer

**First Answer**

```
SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                height: 230,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: ListView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, children: [
                  Card(
                      child: Container(
                    height: 230,
                    width: 170,
                    //color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 170,
                          width: 150,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                      "https://cdn.searchenginejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/shutterstock_1138149659-760x400.png"))),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
                  Card(
                      child: Container(
                    height: 230,
                    width: 180,
                    //color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 170,
                          width: 160,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                      "https://cdn.searchenginejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/shutterstock_1138149659-760x400.png"))),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))
                ])))
```

**Second Answer**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
            Text("Text 1", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            Text("Text 2", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
          ]),
          Container(
            height: 230,
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: [
                Card(
                    child: Container(
                  height: 230,
                  width: 170,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 170,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                    "https://cdn.searchenginejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/shutterstock_1138149659-760x400.png"))),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ))
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you please check the question again? I completely missed a section of Row.

Comment: @Pankaj just give mi couple of min

Comment: @Pankaj You want to add `Text` on each element of `Listview` right like if your elements are `10`  then `10 text` will add right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Text are on top of list view and there will be images in listview. So there will be 2 children. Row will take care of both texts. and ListView will have images.

Comment: @Pankaj you just need to wrap your Listview with Container and apply height to your container you can check my answer again

Comment: There is only one child(ListView) in the container in your answer. Can you update answer with 2 children? First child will be row with 2 text and a  ListView

Comment: @Pankaj Please recheck my answer i Updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227869/discussion-between-shubham-narkhede-and-pankaj).

Comment: @Pankaj Please recheck my answer

Answer (score -2):

you haven't provided direction parameter to ListView widget and also provide shrinkWrap property of ListView to true in order to constraint size of the listView, also you don't need container as a child of ListView after that so remove that too.

Final Code would be following :

```
body: SafeArea(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap : true,
              children: [ 
              
              child: Column(children: [
                Row(children: [
```

Comment: There is no property called `scrollDirection` for children array.

Comment: Not for child array it's for listview.edited.

Comment: Now, please test this on dart pad, you will notice that the card disappear and there shows an error in console. What do that happen?

Comment: It's because you haven't set the constraints so for column widget you need to set size using sizedBox or Container based on your use case.